# td borders were hidden behind tr background color in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, background-color, css-tables

I am writing a webpage that contains a table, when viewed using any browser other than IE8, there is a white border applied to every cell; but when viewed in IE8, the border is hidden behind the row's background color.

(Even IE9 has no problem showing the white borders, and I didn't have earlier IE versions to try on.)

Any idea why?

HTML is as follow:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <form>
    <body>
        <div id="selectFullTextTableDiv">
        <table>
          <tr id="oddRow">
            <td id="cellCheckBox"><input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemOne"></td>
            <td id="itemName">item 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="evenRow">
            <td id="cellCheckBox"><input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemTwo"></td>
            <td id="itemName">item 2</td>   
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
    </form>
</html>
```

And the CSS is as follow:

```
#selectFullTextTableDiv {   position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    }

#selectFullTextTable {  width: 650px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    }

#selectFullTextTable tr {   position:relative;
       top:0px;
       left:0px;
       }


#selectFullTextTable td {   position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px #FFFFFF solid;
    border-top: 2px #FFFFFF solid;
    }

#oddRow {   background-color:#CCCCCC;
         }

#evenRow {  background-color:#FFCC33;
          }

#cellCheckBox { text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px 0px 0px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 0px 0px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
    behavior: url(/CSS3PIE/PIE.htc);
    }

#itemName { margin:2px;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    text-align:left; 
    display:table-cell;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 6px 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 0px;
    behavior: url(/CSS3PIE/PIE.htc);
    }
```

Does anybody see where the problem may be?
It would be greatly appreciated if you can tell me where I made the mistake(s).

Thanks!

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle that replicates this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking your Code. and the first thing that pop to my eyes is that you enclosed your `body` with a `form`.
it's supposed to be the other way around.

**Change this:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <form>
    <body>
    ..
    </body>
    </form>
</html>
```

**To this:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <form>
         ..
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Secondly:** close your `input` tags.

**Change this:**

```
<input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemOne">
<input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemTwo">
```

**To this:**

```
<input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemOne" />
<input name="pid[]" type="checkbox" value="itemTwo" />
```

**Third:**
ID should be unique.
you have multiple elements with the ID. (cellCheckBox, itemName)
I suggest you change them to class, and change your CSS accordingly.

check it and report back.
If the problem still remains, I will investigate further.